# Websockets, micro-controllers and google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, microcontroller, google-compute-engine

I want to control a microcontroller(Internet(Websocket) enabled) from an android from a remote place and it should be bidirectional communication,Hence I choose Websockets instead of polling . But the problem is Google App Engine doesnot allow websockets instead they provide channel Api.Also I am planning to launch an startup based on this. SO the question is..

1. Can I implement channel Api on my microcontroller(either in C or lua) and How?
2. Google Compute engine provides wesockets but I dont know much about networking, So should I consider that option?
3. Are there any other good alternatives to GAE which supports Websockets and can be used for proffesonal use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Websockets on Appengine using managed VM
here you can find an example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-websocketchat-java
Also if what you want to do is server comunication with an android device I recomend you [Google Cloud Message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: Can I use regular Websocket connection from micro-controllers to app engine in this way? It seems too much java classes dependent.

Comment: You can use custom runtimes for this purpouse [link] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/)